# Trying to add asterisk to required input fields

Tags: html, css

I don' think I quite understand `:before` and `:after` since I'm not able to get this working. I'm simply trying to add an asterisk after required fields in a form.

My code is simple:

```
<input id="name" type="text" required="required" autofocus="" placeholder="Name" autocomplete="off" value="" maxlength="40" class="required" name="name" />

/* Required field */
.required:after {
  content: '*';
  color: #EF5F5F;
}
```

Why is this not working?
My fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/3EFTN/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generated content is added as a child of the item you're adding it to. So the browser is doing this (some attributes skipped for brevity):

```
<input class="required">
  <span class="after">*</span>
</input>
```

Which is not valid.

Take a look at [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#before-after-content) to understand it better (it has examples about how the browser interprets it).

Comment: `<input>` cannot be written that way ... It's a self closing tag like `<img />` and `<br />`

Comment: @AhmadAlfy  - Alessandro just demonstrates how a browser handles "css generated code". So it's knowingly invalid code. So no need to down vote.

Comment: @AhmadAlfy I know that, in fact I wrote that the code is not valid, I was just explaining what's happening under the hood.

Comment: @AlessandroVendruscolo  Thanks for the explanation. I didn't vote down though.

Answer (score 1):

`:after` and `:before` selectors are not meant to be used for form elements, such as `input`, so it's impossible to do it with CSS. I'd recommend using jQuery for that or adding another `<span>` after the element.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the info. I was hoping to avoid using extra span tags.

Answer (score 1):

Your css is trying to add the * inside the `<input>` element which is impossible because it can't contain any other element.

Let's put it this way : `:after` means that your content will be inserted **into** and at the end of your selector, `:before` means that your content will be inserted **into** and at the beginning of your element.

You can find a good explanation here: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/07/13/learning-to-use-the-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-in-css/